# Eloquent sortBy date of datetime attribute format

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a model that contains an attribute in datatime format, and i want to sort my collection by this attribute but i don't want to take in consideration the hours and minutes, just the date because i want to achieve a second filter by distance. I am in a situation that i can't change my migrations because am dealing with a huge number of events (+20.000).
I would appreciate any help guys thank you.

This is an explanation example of what am dealing with.

Here's where i handle the filter by date_end and the distance :

```
elseif($data['date'] == true ) {
            $result = $result->sortBy(function($item) {
            return [$item['date_end'], $item['distance_km']];
            });
```

This is the actual results :

```
date_end                     distance
                        |
12/12/2018 15:30        | 107 km
12/12/1018 17:00        | 105 km
01/01/2019 11:45        | 125 km
01/01/2019 12:30        | 120 km
```

And this is what am expecting :

```
date_end                     distance
                          |
12/12/2018 (17:00)        | 105 km
12/12/1018 (15:30)        | 107 km
01/01/2019 (12:30)        | 120 km
01/01/2019 (11:45)        | 125 km
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse it as Carbon instance and sort it by date only.

```
$result = $result->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return [Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['date_end'])->toDateString(), $item['distance_km']];
});
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, i don't know why i went so far by thinking, worked after parsing the needed format Carbon::parse($item['date_end'])->format('d/m/Y').Thank you again and have a nice day :D

Comment: Thanks, if this answer helped you, please consider upvoting/marking it as the right one :)